Ollama, how can I use all the GPUs I have?
I am running Ollma on a 4xA100 GPU server, but it looks like only 1 GPU is used for the LLaMa3:7b model.
How can I use all 4 GPUs simultaneously?
I am not using a docker, just use ollama serve and ollama run.
Or is there a way to run 4 server processes simultaneously (each on different ports) for a large size batch process?
Wed May 15 01:24:29 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          On  | 00000000:17:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   63C    P0             293W / 300W |  39269MiB / 81920MiB |     88%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          On  | 00000000:65:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              51W / 300W |      7MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          On  | 00000000:CA:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              51W / 300W |      7MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          On  | 00000000:E3:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              52W / 300W |      7MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   3420401      C   ...unners/cuda_v11/ollama_llama_server    39256MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Just figured out the way running multiple instances with each on a separate port.
OLLAMA_HOST=xxx.yyy.255.43:11432 ./ollama serve
OLLAMA_HOST=xxx.yyy.255.43:11433 ./ollama serve
OLLAMA_HOST=xxx.yyy.255.43:11434 ./ollama serve
OLLAMA_HOST=xxx.yyy.255.43:11435 ./ollama serve


Late answer here, I ran into the same issue where it would use the 2 GPUs I have so I made a simple shell utility that allows to specify the numbers of servers you want to launch with a specific port range and it works very well!
https://github.com/theodufort/ollama-server-scaler
